# 12.04 and Windows problem

Tags: 12.04, installation, dual-boot

I had Windows XP on my PC and wanted to install Ubuntu as well because I got more comfortable with it in the past few months.

I downloaded iso, burned it and installed it **alongside Windows XP**. I didn't change any options about space on partitions etc, it was preset for 21.4GB of my hard-drive.

Installation was successful, but there wasn't an Ubuntu option in the boot menu. Furthermore, one of my partition lost 21.4GB and I can't find them through Windows XP.

How do I boot Ubuntu? And what happened with my partition space?
I hope I made my problems clear and hope for quick answers.

Answer (score 0):

When your computer boots, does it show a boot loader? Or does it just boot into Windows?
If it shows a boot loader, does it show the Windows boot loader or does it show [GRUB](http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/)?

If it shows GRUB, something isn't correctly configured and you should go [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2).
If it shows the Windows boot loader or no boot loader, I suggest booting from a live CD and install GRUB2 as is documented [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing). From the Live CD you will be able to browse to your new partition.

Comment: it just boot WinXP, doesn't show options. I will try this, and get back to you.